# Sending mail with telnet, empty from address '@'

Tags: smtp, telnet

I'm trying to send mail via telnet.
It does seem to be working as supposted, but the mail from-address ends up looking like this: @.
... no name, nor domain. Just a single @ sign.

The commands i'm using is:

```
telnet mailserver.wherever.com 587
EHLO wherever.com
AUTH LOGIN 
whoever-as-base64
whatever-as-base64
MAIL FROM:whoever@wherever.com
RCPT TO:whoever@overthere.com
DATA
Lorem ipsum.
.
```

... with responses like:

```
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as A98697840F4
```

... but when i take a look in the mail server the queued message is from sender '@'.
Why is that? 
Where could the problem occur? 
Am i doing it wrong, or is the best guess some misconfig in the SMTP?

Yours,

Comment: EHLO should be HELO. The commands are here: http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/email/smtp.html

Comment: Well, i get the same result. With the same '@' sender : /

Comment: @dcaswell It doesn't have to be HELO, EHLO is "extended hello" and the server will reply with any extended smtp commands it supports, such as AUTH or STARTTLS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ... but when i take a look in the mail server the queued message is from sender '@'

I'd bet that's because you've set no headers in the mail, only body is present. Try the following:

```
...    
MAIL FROM:whoever@wherever.com
RCPT TO:whoever@overthere.com
DATA
from:whoever@wherever.com

Lorem ipsum.
.
```